# Python 3 Converting a song in .docx format into .txt format so that chords are correctly alligned

Tags: python-3.x, text, docx

I'm trying to write a program that can convert a song in .docx format (no images) into .txt in python 3. By song I mean lyrics with the chords on the line above like this when opened in Word:

```
  C        F           Am         G
This is a song that I want to convert
```

I originally used python-docx but it didn't work for some of the songs as some chords were hyperlinked so I had to use docx2txt:

```
import docx2txt

doc = docx2txt.process('RandomSong.docx')
print(doc)
#Adapted from https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt
```

This, and the equivalent code for 'import docx', prints the two lines out to the screen but unfortunately doesn't print the chords aligned to the words below them so in the interpreter and subsequently in a text file they look something like this:

```
   C             F                Am           G
This is a song that I want to convert
```

I understand that this is because in word the spaces will be of a different size to other characters whereas they are all the same size as far as a text editor is concerned (correct me if I'm wrong).

So basically, how can I convert docx songs with hyperlinks into txt with Python 3 (preferably with docx2txt) while still having chords in the right place, is there some way of working out what word would be beneath the chords if the file were displayed in MS Word and adjusting the amount of spaces in the txt version to align chords to be above the correct words?

Comment: I guess you will have to load the font, get each character width and do the math (deduce x position of each character). I do not really see how you could do that otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the trouble is I can't seem to find any way of extracting the font from the document in python 3 as it hasn't necessarily been applied through a style.